# ASP application causing Error 500 and causing server to stop frequently

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

The ASP application running on the sql server is causing to stop the IIS server very frequently. The cause it shows in the Error log is: 
"A significant part of sql server process memory has been paged out.This may result in a performance degradation."

Is there any tool which can identify the fault in the web application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the cause to my problem. For each Url redirection, I used the syntax Response.Redirect("/NewPage.aspx"); and this would continue the process even after creating the child process. The fix was: Response.Redirect("/NewPage.aspx", false); This would terminate the process right after calling a child process. That saved a lot of memory used by each process!

Answer (score 3):

No. [You might be able to play with some settings to get your apps to not crash](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/karthick_pk/2012/06/22/a-significant-part-of-sql-server-process-memory-has-been-paged-out/) but in the end, if you have reached your bandwidth cap, you are stuck.

There might not actually be any fault in the web application. Both IIS and SQL Server eat a lot of memory. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/274852/703644), [SQL Server eats ram for lunch](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/09/sysadmins-guide-microsoft-sql-server-memory/)

There might not be *anything* wrong, you might just be running too much on one machine. You will have to provide an actual error or problem. Because right now, our only answer can be to leverage the admin tools, and get more memory.

Comment: I have got 2 web apps running and I once saw an error message that was referring to the particular web application whose implementation has triggered this error now. I can provide more details but where do I find that log file for that asp application?

Comment: If you have more errors you can certainly find those and bring them here. That is well within your ability to find them.